# Serializing in Json.net

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I want just to know Serialize Json data > Csharp to send a Json request to my server
and how to Deserialize the server response to CSharp Object

i using Json.net framework

```
{    
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",    
    "method":"call",    
    "params":    {
        "session_id":"90334",    
        "context":{}    
    },   
    "id":"r5"    
}
```

Comment: I only see statements, no questions here.

Comment: Your question is lacking a question, please tell us what you need, where you are stuck, code involved, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no question here but I am assuming you want to serialize that json string into an object?  Also I would at least post what you have tried and what errors you are receiving if any.  This is per the JSON.net web site found here http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

```
string json = "<you json string>";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
// here is how you would access it
string jsonrpc = (string)o["jsonrpc"];
// access array of you object
JArray sizes = (JArray)o["<arrayName>"];
string arrayEntry = (string)sizes[0];
```

Comment: thnx and i want just to know how to send the Json request to server and Deserialize the response

Comment: Well if you need to send json data to your server you would need to create some kind of web service either classic asmx or a WCF service.  Or mark a method in your aspx site with the Web Method Attribute and have it accept parameters, you can see a good example here.  http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/